# How to GROUP BY an ID the result of a SUM with a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two Tables, one with my contacts informations (`contact`) and one with the users interactions (`notitia`).

Here's an exemple :

```
 SELECT n.contact_id, c.email, c.numero, c.code_postal, n.nbr_click, n.nbr_ouverture,
(
    n.nbr_click * 2
) 
+ 
(
    n.nbr_ouverture * 3
)
as total FROM notitia n LEFT JOIN contact c ON c.id = n.contact_id LIMIT 5
```

The result is :

[image]
Now I'm Trying to do the SUM of the `nbr_click`, `nbr_ouverture` and `total` if the `contact_id` is the same, In my exemple we have 2 times the `contact_id` 3 so the result should be :

[image]

I tried to `GROUP BY n.contact_id` :

```
SELECT n.contact_id, c.email, c.numero, c.code_postal, n.nbr_click, n.nbr_ouverture,
(
    n.nbr_click * 2
) 
+ 
(
    n.nbr_ouverture * 3
)
as total FROM notitia n LEFT JOIN contact c ON c.id = n.contact_id GROUP BY n.contact_id LIMIT 5
```

But here only the first Row with the contact_id = 3 is taken

I also tried to do the SUM :

```
SELECT n.contact_id, c.email, c.numero, c.code_postal, SUM(n.nbr_click), SUM(n.nbr_ouverture),
(
    SUM(n.nbr_click) * 2
) 
+ 
(
    SUM(n.nbr_ouverture) * 3
)
as total FROM notitia n LEFT JOIN contact c ON c.id = n.contact_id LIMIT 5
```

But here everything is added in on row with enormous result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have kind of the mix of the two queries you have written. You should GROUP BY contact_id and then apply SUM to the columns for which you need the SUM. Try this:

```
SELECT n.contact_id, 
       c.email, c.numero, c.code_postal, SUM(n.nbr_click), SUM(n.nbr_ouverture),
(
    SUM(n.nbr_click) * 2
) 
+ 
(
    SUM(n.nbr_ouverture) * 3
)
as total FROM notitia n 
   LEFT JOIN contact c ON c.id = n.contact_id 
   GROUP BY n.contact_id LIMIT 5
```